# Pandas - create total column based on other column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a total column that sums the numbers from another column based on a third column.  I can do this by using `.groupby()`, but that creates a truncated column, whereas I want a column that is the same length.

My code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,2,3,3,3], 'b':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
df['total'] = df.groupby(['a']).sum().reset_index()['b']
```

My result:

```
   a  b  total
0  1  1    1.0
1  2  2    5.0
2  2  3   15.0
3  3  4    NaN
4  3  5    NaN
5  3  6    NaN
```

My desired result:

```
   a  b  total
0  1  1    1.0
1  2  2    5.0
2  2  3    5.0
3  3  4   15.0
4  3  5   15.0
5  3  6   15.0
```

...where each `'a'` column has the same total as the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returning the sum from a groupby operation in pandas produces a column only as long as the number of unique items in the index. Use [transform](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) to produce a column of the same length ("like-indexed") as the original data frame without performing any merges.

```
df['total'] = df.groupby('a')['b'].transform(sum)
>>> df
   a  b  total
0  1  1      1
1  2  2      5
2  2  3      5
3  3  4     15
4  3  5     15
5  3  6     15
```

Comment: not exactly sure why, but that works like a charm.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad it works for you! The documentation (just added a link to it in my answer) says that `transform` produces a "like-indexed" column to the original data frame. This means that it's the same length as the original data frame and isn't just the unique elements from the index.